# Orchard Blog Summary Text

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

On the blog summary page -the one that lists your blog posts- I could do with having a bit more of the text visible from each blog post.

Is this possible? 
I cant see it anywhere in the settings and for some reason shape tracing isnt letting me see what the template is for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through reading other post I found that the view responsible for this was **Parts_Common_Body_Summary**. So I copied this from the core / common folder of orchard and copied it across to my themes view folder, before renaming it to **Parts_Blog_Summary**

I then set-up a rule for this in **Placement.info** as follows:

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary="Content:after;Alternate=Parts_Blog_Summary"/>
</Match>    
</Match>
```

This just left me the task of altering the string length in the new alternate view:

```
var body = new HtmlString(Html.Excerpt(bodyHtml, 350).ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</p>" + Environment.NewLine + "<p>"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do the same thing recently on Orchard v1.6. You're using the shape tracing so you're going in the right direction. The [orchard documentation for alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) and [placement](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info) cover this. There's a good example of this kind of modification on [Tony Johnson's Argument Exception Blog](http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/05/real-world-orchard-cms-part-4-cleaning.html).

As per Phil's answer, you need to modify the placement.info in your current theme to use an alternate view like so;

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary="Content:5;Alternate=Parts_BlogPostSummaryBody"/>
</Match>
</Match>
```

And then add an alternate part named "Content-BlogPost.Summary.cshtml" in your theme's view folder;

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement.ViewModels
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Core.Common.Models

@{      
ContentItem item = Model.ContentItem;
string title = Model.Title.ToString();
BodyPart bpItem = item.As<BodyPart>();
string linkUrl = Url.ItemDisplayUrl(item);
}

<h4>@Html.ItemDisplayLink(title, item)</h4>
<div class="publishinfo">@Model.ContentItem.CommonPart.PublishedUtc by @Model.ContentItem.CommonPart.Owner.UserName</div>
      <div>
   <p>@Html.Raw(@bpItem.Text)</p>
</div>
```